# UIColor display not exactly correct?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uicolor

I input this in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231/255.0 green:77/255.0 blue:77/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

and create label in xib , set color e74d4d(which convert to rgb is 231,77,77)

I want to show image on the website , but it tells me I need 10 reputation.

I debug the code,and find this,

```
(lldb) po self.view.backgroundColor
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.905882 0.301961 0.301961 1

(lldb) po self.label.textColor
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.87161 0.208926 0.237916 1
```

[image: this is screenshot of the simulator]

[image: this is the code with UIColor]

[image: this color setup]

[image: i even set this to clear color,but didn't work]

Comment: What's you issue, wrong color or conversion?

Comment: upload your images to a hosting site and give the links here. One of use can inline them, or, if another person upvotes you you can inline them yourself.

Comment: I agree. Make sure your images are using the sRGB color profile.

Comment: Values should be float.

Comment: If you mean that you have a visual mismatch between in-code/IB colors, then you should [check this out](http://inaka.net/blog/2014/09/05/getting-the-right-colors-in-your-ios-app/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while you are passing value for UIColor always use float value.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:77.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

also use the same float value while you are converting to other format.

Edit: From the comments.
Dividing 231/255.0 and 231.0/255.0 are the same. Yes it is, but i have written that always pass float value means in for both values.

As user doesn't provided second conversation i thought function is using 255 for devision instead of 255.0 as a result it will be a integer value.

Try below code with RGBFromUIColor macro one by one, it will show different output.

```
self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231/255 green:77/255 blue:77/255 alpha:1.0];
self.titleLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:77.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.titleLabel3.backgroundColor = RGBFromUIColor(231, 77, 77);
self.titleLabel4.backgroundColor = RGBFromUIColor(231.0, 77.0, 77.0)
```

Now suppose macro for RGBFromUIColor is like below

```
#define RGBFromUIColor(r, g, b) \[UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]
```

or like this

```
#define RGBFromUIColor(r, g, b) \[UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255 green:(g)/255 blue:(b)/255 alpha:1]
```

The last RGBFromUIColor will not have same value in case it doen't devided by float i.e 255.0

Comment: 231/255.0 is .09058... so int/float conversion probably isn't at play here.

Comment: sometimes it makes differance.

Comment: can you please mention how it makes the difference?

Comment: There is no difference as when operation perform on int with float the type cast to float value.

Comment: Exactly Aashish, I agree with you.

Comment: because you are using ints in your gist, in the above code the ints are implicitly cast to floats since they are divided by a float.

Comment: @PaulCezanne i have run the code in xcode, i am using gist as the comment is to big to add.
Now my point is same, he(fang) doesn't provided the second conversion.
I suggest you to run the code.

Comment: No, I believe you. Your code will fail but your code is different from fangs. 77 is not the same as 77/255.0.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you are experiencing, but it I have previously seen some color problems with the OS X Color Picker due to the color calibration on my display. Sometimes it seems to select the color components by display value and then convert them to sRGB, when you actually want no conversion at all.

I would try the either of the following:

1. Use the ‘RGB Sliders’ color picker panel.
2. Paint the color in an image without a color profile, open the image in Preview.app and use the pipette tool to select that color.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the text lable colour is not the same as your background colour?

I suspect your problem is that you are setting the text color to e74d4d which is a 24 bit value, no transparency value (the A in RGBA and ARGB). Try ffe74d4d or e74d4dff which set the transparency to opaque (alpha to 1). Even better, simply set it the same way as you set the background color, and iOS will automatically set the transparency to opaque.